# Java ArrayBlockingQueue for implementing muliple producers and multiple consumer

Tags: java

Say in my system I have multiple producer threads and multiple consumer threads and I am planning to use the ArrayBlockingQueue as the shared resources. Now what i see from the implementation of ArrayBlockingQueue is when it does insert() it does call notEmpty.signal instead of notEmpty.signalAll. Therefore, what i wonder about is will it wake up all consumer threads who are waiting for the elements, or will it only wake up one consumer thread? If it wakes up only one consumer thread, what i can use to implement multiple consumer thread in my app?

Comment: You want all your consumers to consume every element from the queue?

Comment: no, the consumer threads does not need to consume all elements

Comment: So why do you need to notify all consumer threads?

Comment: ah, I see, so looks like the case is if the consumer threads does not need to consume all elements that the producers are producing, then we can use ArrayBlockingQueue, right?

Comment: Right. `poll` removes and returns the next element in the queue. Only one thread would get it anyway.